# Average of Monte-Carlo estimates: Increasing observations vs. iterations

Tags: monte-carlo, unbiased-estimator

In the context of Monte Carlo simulations, I would like to understand better the difference between increasing the number of iterations vs. the number of observations.

As an example, please consider the following simple R code that is supposed to confirm the unbiasedness of OLS:

```
set.seed(1)

beta <- c(1, 2)

Niter <- 100
NObs  <- 1000

estimates <- matrix(as.numeric(NA), nrow = Niter, ncol = 2)

for(i in 1:Niter) {

  x <- rnorm(n = NObs)
  u <- rnorm(n = NObs)

  y <- beta[1] + beta[2] * x + u

  reg <- lm(y ~ x)
  estimates[i, ] <- coef(reg)
}

print(colMeans(estimates))
# [1] 1.001352 1.997076
```

The average of the estimates is pretty close to the true `beta` values and would become even closer if I increased `Niter` or `NObs`.

In the current case, I am only interested in the average of the estimates. If I was interested in their distribution, I would need a sufficiently large `Niter` to get as many observed estimates as possile. **But when I only want to check the average, what is the difference between increasing `Niter` vs. `NObs`?**

Increasing `Niter` (100) by 1 gives `NObs` (1000) observations more. Is this equivalent to increasing `NObs` by 10 which also gives 1000 additional observations over the 100 iterations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expected value of `colMeans` will allways be unbiased, no matter whether you inrease `NObs` or `Niter`, but the difficult part of your question is, whether the variances will change.

We know that `estimates` $\sim N_2(\mu = \beta, ~ \Sigma = \sigma_\varepsilon^2 \cdot (X_{NObs}^T X_{NObs})^{-1})$ with $\beta$ being `beta`, $X_{NObs}$ being `cbind(1, x)` with `length(x) == NObs` and $\sigma_\varepsilon^2$ being `1`. So `colMeans(estimates))` is a linear combination of normally distributed random variables. In formula `colMeans(estimates))` $\sim N_2(\mu = \beta,~\Sigma =  \sigma_\varepsilon^2 \cdot (X_{NObs}^T X_{NObs})^{-1} /Niter )$

In your case $(X_{NObs}^T X_{NObs})^{-1} = (n \cdot \sum(x^2) - (\sum(x))^2)^{-1} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} \sum (x^2) & -\sum(x) \\ -\sum(x) & n \end{pmatrix}$ what can be written as $(n^2 \cdot var(x))^{-1} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} \sum (x^2) & -\sum(x) \\ -\sum(x) & n \end{pmatrix}$ with $var(x)$ being the *uncorrected* empirical variance - here $1$. For reasons of clarity I use $n = NObs$.

So your question is whether the change in $Niter$ from $100$ to $101$ changes $\begin{pmatrix} \sum (x^2)/n^2 & -\sum(x)/n^2 \\ -\sum(x)/n^2 & 1/n \end{pmatrix}/Niter$ in the same way as a change in $NObs$ from $1000$ to $1010$.
If we assume, that $\sum_1^{1010}(x^2) = \sum_1^{1000}(x^2)+ \sum_{1001}^{1010}(x^2) = 1.01 \cdot \sum_{1}^{1000} (x^2)$ and $-\sum_1^{1010}(x) = -\sum_1^{1000}(x) - \sum_{1001}^{1010}(x) = - 1.01 \cdot \sum_{1}^{1000} (x)$, incresing `NObs` by `10` is equivalent to multiply the covariance matrix by a factor $1.01^{-1}$ (note that $n_{new} = 1010 = 1.01 \cdot n$ for $n=1000$).

So $\begin{pmatrix} \sum (x^2)/n^2 & -\sum(x)/n^2 \\ -\sum(x)/n^2 & 1/n \end{pmatrix}/(100+1)$ is equivalent to $\begin{pmatrix} \sum (x^2)/n^2 & -\sum(x)/n^2 \\ -\sum(x)/n^2 & 1/n \end{pmatrix}\cdot (1.01)^{-1} /100$ (because $1/(100+1) = 1/101 = 1/(1.01 \cdot 100)$).

---

I did a small "meta"-simulation study, where I ran your simulation 100 times under both Settings. Setting 1 was to increase `Niter` by 1, and setting 2 was to increase `NObs` by 10. In each meta-Simulation run, I saved the `colMeans` in a matrix `colmeans1` and `colmeans2`. Plotting `the entries from both matrices doesn't contradict the theoretical finding of both settings being equivalent.

```
set.seed(1)
S <- 100

colmeans1  <- matrix(NA, nrow = S, ncol = 2)
colmeans2  <- matrix(NA, nrow = S, ncol = 2)

#Setting 1: increasing Niter by 1
for(s in 1:S){
beta <- c(1, 2)

Niter <- 100 + 1
NObs  <- 1000

estimates <- matrix(as.numeric(NA), nrow = Niter, ncol = 2)

for(i in 1:Niter) {

  x <- rnorm(n = NObs)
  u <- rnorm(n = NObs)

  y <- beta[1] + beta[2] * x + u

  reg <- lm(y ~ x)
  estimates[i, ] <- coef(reg)
}
colmeans1[s,]  <- colMeans(estimates)
}



#Setting 1: increasing NObs by 10
for(s in 1:S){
beta <- c(1, 2)

Niter <- 100 
NObs  <- 1000 + 10

estimates <- matrix(as.numeric(NA), nrow = Niter, ncol = 2)

for(i in 1:Niter) {

  x <- rnorm(n = NObs)
  u <- rnorm(n = NObs)

  y <- beta[1] + beta[2] * x + u

  reg <- lm(y ~ x)
  estimates[i, ] <- coef(reg)
}
colmeans2[s,]  <- colMeans(estimates)
}
```

[image: setting1 vs. setting2]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm not sure whether I can follow your reasoning till the end, but I will think of it for a while …

Comment: For potential naive readers who want to reproduce the plot, this generates a (less nice) version of it: `plot(colmeans1[,2]~colmeans1[,1], col = "red")
points(colmeans2[,2]~colmeans2[,1], col = "blue", pch = 4)`.